# Where is Cisco IPSec shared key?

Tags: macos, vpn

I would like to decode shared secret of OS X native Cisco IPSec profile. Then try to decode it. I tried to look in /private/etc with hope that there is CiscoSystemsVPNClient folder, but no luck... Where is it located?